# spring data - get beans in a custom default repository implementation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-commons

Im trying to upgrade my project from `spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE` to `spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE`.

In the `1.4.3.RELEASE` the way I have used my custom implementation of repositories is as follow:

1. Made an interface `MyCustomRepositroy` that extends `JpaRepository`
2. Had a class `MyCustomRepositoryImpl` that implements `MyCustomRepositroy` and `SimpleJpaRepository`. In that class I have changed the behavior of
   the of `save`, `find` and `delete` methods, because I needed a
   ceratin behavior for entitys of certain type (lets say that I need a
   custom `save` for all entitys that implements `Special` interface)
3. I made a `MyCustomJpaRepositoryFactoryBean` that extends `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean`. In that factory, I've overridden `createRepositoryFactory` and gave it my `MyRepositoryFactory` implementation.
   In `MyRepositoryFactory` implementation I've overridden the `getTargetRepository`, and `getRepositoryBaseClass`.In these methods, I check if the entity is of type `Special`, and if so, I return `MyCustomRepositoryImpl`, otherwise I return `SimpleJpaRepository`.

Also, I can get the beanFactory in my `MyCustomRepositoryImpl` class because I call my own constructor of `MyCustomRepositoryImpl` that has also a beanFactory parameter via `getTargetRepositoryViaReflection`.

Now, with the new version (that uses `spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE`), I cannot override the Factory class, and hence can't decide for each entitiy which implementation to give, and have no way to get the beanFactory.

Is there any way I can get what I want?

Sorry for the mess, but I cannot post my code here.

P.S - my project is a spring based library, so I can't do anything to the entitys because my clients declare them, all I know that some entitys implement the `Special` interface and some don't

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to figure out what happened in 1.5.9.RELEASE, but in the meantime, just as a fyi - 1.5.6.RELEASE works ok.

I am having the same issue when trying to update from 1.5.6.RELEASE to 1.5.9.RELEASE